# How to check bash shell finished in php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I am having difficulty processing bash shell in php.
My problem is as below.
I have 3 tasks corresponding to 3 files bash shell (task1.sh, task2.sh, task3.sh). When task1.sh finishes processing, task2.sh will automatically execute, when task2.sh finishes processing, task3.sh will automatically execute.

Initially, I wrote a file called task.sh and embedded task1.sh, task2.sh, task3.sh into it. But I want to embed these 3 tasks into a php file.

For example: I create task.php and do the following:

- If task1.sh fails, it will display popout (alert) error message.
- If task1.sh processing is complete then task2.sh will continue to be automatically done.
- The processing of task2.sh and task3.sh is similar to the above.

All 3 tasks I want to run backgroud. The problem is that when I run the background bash shell, I will not be able to check the failed error statement (the result always returns to 0).

I have learned a lot and consulted many documents but it did not help me.

I hope you can support me.

Sorry, my english very poor.

Comment: When you say the bash shell's will run in the background, how within PHP are you calling the scripts? Just that if it is truly in the background, PHP could be finished before the scripts have and therefore has no way to signal to the user if one of the scripts fail.

Comment: @JimGrant Yes. I know what you mean. Is there any way to check the bash shell's finished in php?

Comment: If you need to check in PHP whether the script has finished or not, then it is probably best to call it synchronously. That way you can check the return code of the first script, but then it will also mean that the PHP script will not complete till the scripts have finished. The knock on effect could be that the connection with the browser will be lost and the output from the PHP script not displayed. it all depends on how long the individual scripts run for and if any processing on the PHP end is required during it running.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `$retval` argument of `exec()`.

```php
<?php

exec('task1.sh', $output, $retval);
if ($retval !== 0) {
  // task 1 failed
  exit('Error running task1: ' . implode("<br/>\n", $output));
}

exec('task2.sh', $output, $retval);
if ($retval !== 0) {
  // task 2 failed
  exit('Error running task1: ' . implode("<br/>\n", $output));
}

exec('task3.sh', $output, $retval);
if ($retval !== 0) {
  // task 3 failed
  exit('Error running task1: ' . implode("<br/>\n", $output));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the function:

```
exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] ) : string
```

With:

> **output** :
>   If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().
>
> **return_var** :
>   If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

Thus you could use $output and $result_var to check the execution errors of your shells.

Regards